# Query free API, IP blocking

Tags: php, api, ip, fopen, bigdata

I am using some API which is free. 
I am using PHP script which is using fopen to download JSON from API.
When I make to many requests(eg. 2 requests every minute) API is blocking my PHP server IP.
Is there a way to solve it and possibility to make more requests (I don't want to DDoS attack)?
Is there better solution than use of many PHP servers with different IP's?

Comment: Is it an API that you can pay for to reduce the rate-limiting?

Comment: this api is free and have not paid version ;/

Comment: You should read their docs/contact their developers. You must be doing something they don't support, or expect..

Comment: If you do not **need** to issue request so frequently, caching the data locally for a while could be an option: Request data and store it locally if the data (file) does not exist or is too old. Always read data from local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite abstract question as we don't know the actual api you are talking about.

But, usually, if an api implement a rate limit, it shows this kind of header in it's answer:

- X-Rate-Limit-Limit: the rate limit ceiling for that given request
- X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
- X-Rate-Limit-Reset: the remaining window before the rate limit resets in UTC epoch seconds

Please check the docs (this one is from twitter, https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting).